# How much space do "Shared Streams" take up on an iOS device?

Tags: ios, icloud, photo-stream

In iOS 6 and 7 there's a section in the Photos app that allows you to share photos with other people and other people to share photos with you.

1. When others share with me, are the photos copied to my harddrive? Or do they purely reside in the cloud?
2. If I add the same photo to two different streams, will it duplicate the amount of space used on my phone? Or does Apple intelligently make a reference link instead of a copy?

Answer (score 6):

> - When others share with me, are the photos copied to my hard drive? Or do they purely reside in the cloud?

Photos shared with you (or photos you share) get copied to your (or others') devices through `iCloud`. They reside on `iCloud` for just 30 days to give adequate time for all devices to sync them from the cloud. See [iCloud: My Photo Stream FAQ](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT4486)

> - If I add the same photo to two different streams, will it duplicate the amount of space used on my phone? Or does Apple intelligently make a reference link instead of a copy?

It won't add another copy on your phone across your photo streams, but there will be a photo stream specific copy that's separate from the camera roll (and any other albums the photo may be part of).

The quality of the photos shared will also vary across devices. See [iCloud Photo Stream and Image Quality](http://www.ilounge.com/index.php/articles/comments/icloud-photo-stream-and-image-quality/)

---

There are three groups you see under `Settings > General > Usage > Photos & Camera`:

1. `Camera Roll` - this is for photos you have taken on the device *as well as* photos you have saved to the `Camera Roll` from (others') photo streams you have subscribed to. If you have `Photo Stream` enabled, any photo you take with your camera will be added to the `Camera Roll` and `Photo Stream` (with `Photo Stream` being restricted to the recent 1000 photos on iOS devices; there are no restrictions on photo streams on computers).
2. `Photo Library` - this is for photos that have been synced from iTunes (the source of those usually being iPhoto or Aperture on OS X).
3. `Photo Stream` - this is for photos from your and others' photo streams. If you delete a photo from your photo stream, it will get deleted from all other devices that sync to the same `iCloud` account.

Comment: When I go into `Settings > General > Usage > Photos & Camera`, I see three sections: 1) Camera Roll. 2) Photo Library. 3) Photo Stream. Camera roll is well understood as the photos I've taken on my local storage. However, I don't understand the last two. I have no idea what "Photo Libary" means apart from Camera Roll. And as for "Photo Stream", is that only my photo stream or does it also include other people's streams shared with me?

Comment: I've added some information about camera roll, photo library and photo stream.

Answer (score 1):

As of my experience the whole Photostream feature needs about 1GB of space on your iOS device.

When I reinstalled my iPhone recently and haven't taken any photo yet - iTunes showed up a usage of ≈1.1GB for photos, just because I had the Photostream activated.

The interesting thing is, that I had many photos in my Photostream, that were made with my DSLR and synced into the Photostream via iPad. All of these ≈600 Photos would have used a lot more that these 1.1GB, so I guess you get a smaller version of your photos for your iPhone. However you get the pictures in full-size in iPhoto on a Mac.

Answer (score 0):

```
Settings > General > Usage > Manage Storage > Photos & Camera > Shared Photo Stream
```

Shows 15.1 MB for me, and I'm in a shared stream between  many people and thousands of photos

iOSv8.1

Answer (score 0):

The answer is wrong: "Photos shared with you (or photos you share) get copied to your (or others') devices through iCloud. They reside on iCloud for just 30 days to give adequate time for all devices to sync them from the cloud."

The 30 day limit is only for "My Photo Streaming", not for "iCloud photo sharing". The shared photo stream will be there until you manually delete them.